# Why can't I see jpg images in kijiji upload?

Tags: internet, upload

I am trying to upload images for an ad in kijiji and I can't see all of the jpg images present on my desktop when I want to upload them. I can see them as jpg images on the desktop but not on the kijiji upload screen, though it shows some of my images.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that filenames in Linux (and, therefore, Ubuntu) are case-sensitive. Kijiji requires the filename to end with .jpg or .JPG (can't remember), and the images on your desktop probably have the opposite case.

Rename the files with the same case as Kijiji and... voilà!